# change body class based on img src or id using jquery

Tags: jquery, addclass

I'm using this slideshow:
http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider
and I'd like to change the body class for each slide, so I can then apply a different background color.

I've got something like this:

```
if($('#featured').find('img[src="/01.jpg"]')) {
    //alert('img exists');
    $('body').addClass('option_a');
} else if
    //alert('img dosnt exists');
    ($('#featured').find('img[src="/02.jpg"]')) {
    //alert('img exists');
    $('body').addClass('option_b');
} else {
    $('body').addClass('option_c');
}
```

But my javascript is quite poor still, so I could use some guidance, or an alternative approach. Many thanks :)

Comment: .find() returns an object which is always true so you need to use .find().length to make sure it has some items.

Comment: Your current code only adds the `option_a` class to the body, you can  consider using `afterSlideChange` callback function of orbit. Also note that when you add a class for adding another class you should remove other classes, in this case using `attr('class', '...')` is better.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be preferable to store information regarding styling, that depends on the images, in the image's tags.

This way you don't have to change your javascript code when adding a new image to the slides.

```
<div id="featured"> 
     <img src="overflow.jpg" alt="Overflow: Hidden No More" data-class="option-a" />
     <img src="captions.jpg"  alt="HTML Captions" data-class="option-b" />
     <img src="features.jpg" alt="and more features" data-class="option-c" />
</div>

<script>
$('#featured').orbit({afterSlideChange: function() {
    $('body').attr('class', $(this).data('class'));
}});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi all, your input was invaluable. I'm using the afterSlideChange callback function from the orbit slideshow, as recommended, and your script Roman. Thanks!